# Firefox not taking note of /etc/hosts?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, localhost, hosts, hosts-file

I've set `foo.com` to `127.0.0.1` in my `/etc/hosts` file in (located here on Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`).

Though [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) loads foo.com with the one hosted locally on port 80, [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) loads the actual [foo.com](http://foo.com).

**How do I get Firefox to load my locally pointed foo.com?**

Comment: Firefox doesn't do that. It uses the OS DNS resolver to convert names to IP addresses. So it depends on how the resolver is configured. Applications such as Firefox have nothing to do with it.

Comment: So how do I configure its resolver to resolve `foo.com` as `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Does Firefox have a proxy manually configured?  If so DNS will be offloaded to the proxy server.

Comment: @AT That's a Windows admin thing, and I don't do Windows. The fact that that file is in a directory named "drivers" is completely bizarre. I think there is some GUI tool to set these.

Comment: @Zoredache Nope, it has precisely the same proxy settings as Chrome. Keith: Not sure.

Answer (score 3):

@guns answer to another question ([about DNS lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841421/mac-osx-lion-dns-lookup-order)) helped me out on this issue.  Basically, if a site has an IPv6 address, you need that in your hosts file, too.

```
127.0.0.1 foo.com
::1 foo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be an issue due to a new feature called "DNS over HTTPS" (DoH).

To disable DNS over HTTPS go to **Options -> General -> Network Settings**. Then scroll down and deselect the checkmark in 'Enable DNS over HTTPs'

(In other languages, this is called differently, but should be found in Settings, if you search for "DNS")

Comment: A clear way to tell whether one is caused by DoH: the hosts file cannot _override_ existing sites, but it can _add_ non-existing sites. This is because all major browsers (Firefox, Chrome) fall back to DNS if DoH didn’t find the domain. The fallback is intended for corporate environment; most companies have intranet sites hosted under `*.corp.example.com`. It also means that one can consider a test-only domain to bypass this restriction, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem before.  It seems like Firefox is caching the /etc/hosts file in some fashion.  Give it some time.

Comment: how do you force to clear it? I tried 'Clear your history' but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

set both www and non-www version of domain name at /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 foo.com
127.0.0.1 www.foo.com
```

It is because firefox checks `www.foo.com` domain after initial DNS response of no server at `foo.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Trusted Recursive Resolver exceptions with the `network.trr.excluded-domains` setting in `about:config` to exclude domains. Set it's value to a comma-separated list of domains like 'localhost,local,foo.com'