# /etc/hosts file not properly blocking site in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, blocking, hosts-file

I am trying to block certain sites from my computer (namely, reddit) in order to get some work done.
However, modifying the /etc/hosts file seems to have no effect. I am working under Ubuntu 18.04

Here is the content of my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       MY_COMPUTER_NAME
127.0.0.1 reddit.com 
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com
127.0.0.1 np.reddit.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I would expect this file to block all my connection attempts to [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com)   But even after rebooting the computer/browser, my browser can still access reddit normally when I type  [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com)  in the address bar.

It seems I cannot manage to make the /etc/hosts file work. There is no website that I have managed to block yet (it's not just a reddit thing)

How can I block access to a website from my computer using /etc/hosts ? How can I assert if my /etc/hosts file is working properly ?

When I try to ping the website, here is what happens :

```
ping -c5 www.reddit.com
PING www.reddit.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
```

I am using Firefox, it turns out it was the problem : Firefox does NOT use /etc/hosts by default.

Comment: What happens if you `ping -c5 www.reddit.com` from the command line - doesit use 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: See answers (and at least one useful comment) here: [*How do `/etc/hosts` and DNS work together to resolve hostnames to IP addresses?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/499792/108618)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Karnil's comment, I was able to find the relevant comment [here] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499792/how-do-etc-hosts-and-dns-work-together-to-resolve-hostnames-to-ip-addresses)

Namely, the following comment :

```
Beware that many Web browsers implement their own DNS servers and DNS cache and do not consult any name-lookup mechanisms that have been configured on the system. In other words, some Web browsers completely ignore /etc/hosts and the locally-defined name servers. It's quite confusing to witness the first time around. (Looking at you, Chromium-based browsers!)
```

It's the case of Firefox. I used the response provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1433325/does-firefox-ignore-the-hosts-file-how-to-make-firefox-honor-the-hosts-file), which is to change the network.dns.offline-localhost to false in about:config

Additionnally, the procedure described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https)  (disable "DNS over https") was necessary for my Firefox to honor the /etc/hosts file. It seems to be a rather recent evolution from Firefox