# How can I find the IP address of a web site in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I would like to know what IP address my browser is currently using to access the host of a web site.

In most cases I could potentially use a tool like `ping` to show what my OS thinks the IP is, but it's possible in at least [one case](https://superuser.com/questions/1433325/does-firefox-ignore-the-hosts-file-how-to-make-firefox-honor-the-hosts-file) that Firefox may disagree with what the Operating System uses.

Top search results seem to find Mozilla support threads that basically recommend add-ons, but I don't want to trust an add-on, and I don't know whether they will necessarily even report the same IP that Firefox uses internally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this via the developer console, available from <kbd>F12</kbd>. From there, navigate to the Network tab and hover the Domain column. You'll see the IP address and port in a tooltip.

[image]

You can also add the Remote IP column to the table. Right-click the heading row and choose 'Remote IP' from the list. The column will then appear in the table

[image]

Comment: According to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1154632 this does not work for cached items, so something like Ctrl+F5 may be necessary.

Comment: There’s also an available column named “Remote IP”.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer.