# How to block a website like crazygames.com?

Tags: windows, website, blocking, hosts, hosts-file

I am trying to block **crazygames.com** website using the hosts file but it doesn't work.

I added this line into the hosts file.

127.0.0.1 crazygames.com

*Pinging crazygames.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128*

Ping works but the website can still be opened in a browser (Chrome, Edge), even after running flushdns, clear browser cache/cookies, restart PC.

There's no proxy configured.

For some other websites, it works while it doesn't for a few games websites.

Why did this happen? Any other way to block a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following in the `hosts` file :

```
127.0.0.1 crazygames.com
127.0.0.1 www.crazygames.com
```

This worked to block the website in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

For Firefox, see the post
[Does Firefox ignore the hosts file? How to make Firefox honor the hosts file](https://superuser.com/questions/1433325/does-firefox-ignore-the-hosts-file-how-to-make-firefox-honor-the-hosts-file)